# Netsnmp library usage

Tags: c, linux

I am trying to write a C program using the netsnmp library for system observation over a network. I'd like to know more details on this. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Need more details. It is not clear what do you want to ask. What are your inputs, what are your outputs.
What system do you want to monitor?

Comment: Over a network multiple machines will be connected. Say, I have to query for a particular machines temperature value. How do I do this in C?

Comment: Please take a look at [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read the [netsnmp](http://www.net-snmp.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) tutorials.  [This one](http://www.net-snmp.org/wiki/index.php/TUT:Simple_Application) shows you how to query a device once you know the ip address.   Start simple and work up to multiple devices.